# id never repeated for different entities in Symfony2 with Doctrime ORM

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm developing a custom user bundle for a symfony2 application which has 3 types of users: Administrator, Professor and Student. Each type of user has an identifier (the national identity number, in Spanish: **dni**) and another data like name, lastName, etc. (data between different user's type are disjoint)

My problem is that I need that a **dni** is never repeated, regardless of the user's type.

I have used the UniqueEntity annotation and this works, but only with entities of the same type.

How I could do it for entities of different type?

I have thought to use the callback annotation and check with a query that in the other entities there is no entity with that dni but for that I have to use the entity manager inside of an entity and this is a bad practise.

Do exist another way to do this?

Greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. That is the final snippet (Thanks to ladislav_prague)

```
$repository_a = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Administrator');
    $administrator_dni_used = $repository_a->createQueryBuilder('a')->where('a.dni = \'' . $dni_to_check . '\'')->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

$repository_p = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Professor');
$professor_dni_used = $repository_a->createQueryBuilder('p')->where('p.dni = \'' . $dni_to_check . '\'')->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

$repository_s = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Student');
$student_dni_used = $repository_a->createQueryBuilder('s')->where('s.dni = \'' . $dni_to_check . '\'')->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();


if(is_null($administrator_dni_used) and is_null($professor_dni_used) and is_null($student_dni_used)){

// add new user

}else{

    $error = new FormError("There is already an user with that dni");
    $editForm->get('dni')->addError($error);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new entity (let's call it Dni), which collects dni values from all tables for examlple as AdministratorDni, ProfessorDni and StudentDni properties associated by OneToOne association with each of already existing entities.

Then every time before you add a new Administrator/Professor/Student, create a doctrine query to select max value from AdministratorDni, ProfessorDni and StudentDni. You will get three most current dni maximums, so then just use max() function to get the actual highest dni.

Comment: This is not a solution because the last user inserted may to have a dni lesser than the first user inserted.

Comment: I want to say that the insertion of users is not ordered by dni. In fact, an Administrator can add any type of user at any time.

Comment: I understand. Should be dni value used as machine-generated PRIMARY_KEY or does it come as an human input value?

Answer (score 0):

If the last user inserted may to have a dni lesser than the first user, then check existing dni before creating new user. Like this:

```
$repository_a = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Administrator');
$administrator_dni_used = $repository_a->createQueryBuilder('a')->where('a.dni = \'' . $dni_to_check . '\'')->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

$repository_p = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Professor');
$professor_dni_used = $repository_a->createQueryBuilder('p')->where('p.dni = \'' . $dni_to_check . '\'')->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

$repository_s = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Student');
$student_dni_used = $repository_a->createQueryBuilder('s')->where('s.dni = \'' . $dni_to_check . '\'')->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();


if(is_null($administrator_dni_used) and is_null($professor_dni_used) and is_null($student_dni_used)){

// add new user

}
```